# MEANJS stack and email configuration

Tags: mean-stack, email, meanjs

I am trying to configure email service in MEAN stack.

I have the following configuration :

```
mailer: {
    from: process.env.MAILER_FROM || 'xyz@gmail.com',
    options: {
        service: process.env.MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER || 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID || 'xyz@gmail.com',
            pass: process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD || 'aaaaaa'
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me error "Failure sending email" - every time i try to send email.

what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to complete a few steps regarding your gmail account configuration, namely [allowing less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) in your Google security settings.

Comment: Hi @user583726 now I'm facing same issue in my meanjs app. so can you please help us... how would you setup the email preference in yours app, can you please give some examples as well to know the exact solution... the error shows like  ("Failure sending email") , so please give me the exact solution...thanks...

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam if it is a gmail account that you're trying to use you have to follow what I wrote in the answer. If you're using other email service and you're getting the same error you are either using wrong email details (user, pass, service, etc) or there's something in the email service that might be preventing the email message from being sent.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, then i want to know one think , you have given the email id as a xyz@gmail.com and password is 'aaaaaa' is this default setup (or) yours account id and password?

Comment: It will only work if you setup a correct username, password and email service. It will **not** work if you set a random email or password there. For testing purposes you can use your own email account from gmail or other service. But if your app goes to production you should be using a dedicated email created for that specific purpose. "xyz@gmail.com" and "aaaa" are just an example and should not be used as they will not work.

Comment: thanks for your answer we will check and update you...thanks